# CSS - Create horizontal stripe

Tags: css

I am trying to create a horizontal stripe background within an existing div using CSS that looks like this...

[image]

I know I could use a repeating image but I am trying to achieve this using CSS so that I can modify the color dynamically.

This needs to be background as content will be going inside the div.

Anyone have an example?

Comment: Please add code , so your issue will provide more understanding

Comment: An example of what? 3 divs stacked vertically?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. More details can be found here at css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

```css
.stripe {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #5d9634, #5d9634 50%, #538c2b 50%, #538c2b);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: 100% 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a linear gradient:

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
.canvas{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: repeating-linear-gradient( 
            180deg,
            tomato 40%,
            tomato 50%,
            #fff 50%,
            #fff 100%);
```

```html
<div class="canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `repeating-linear-gradient`

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    #464e96,
    #464e96 40%,
    #58d27b 20%,
    #58d27b 60%
  );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea with gradient where you can easily control the size of the stripe:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  
  background:                         /* width:100% height:20px;*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) center /   100%          20px,
    blue;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below snippet. You can do this using `position` property

```css
.bg-img{
position:relative;
height:100vh;
background-color:darkblue
}
.divider{
position:absolute;
background-color:green;
height:20px;
width:100%;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%)

}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
<div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.Div1{
background:#464e96;
width:70%;
height:70px;
color:white;
}

.Div2{
background:#58d27b;
width:70%;
height:25px;
color:white;
}

.Div3{
background:#464e96;
width:70%;
height:70px;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1"> </div>
<div  class="Div2"> </div>
<div  class="Div3"></div>
```